# Alternative to 'evalin' with MATLAB App Designer

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler, matlab-app-designer

I'm creating an app that I eventually want to compile as a standalone application.  The app constructs a GUI for a preexisting MATLAB program and I utilize the evalin function twice in the following manner.

First, I run a 'start' function as follows

```
evalin("base",'func.start')
```

This instantiates a number of variables which are necessary to run the GUI.
Next, I run the following code to read in one of the variables into the AppDesigner workspace.

```
fx = evalin("base",'fx')
```

I wanted to see if there was a deployable alternative to 'evalin' that could be compiled by the MATLAB Compiler.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just run `func.start` in your function? Why does it need to be evaluated in the base workspace? -- Just to be clear, from the details you give we have no idea what is going on or why the `evalin` would be necessary. In principle you don't need `evalin`, unless this preexisting MATLAB program does something really stupid and needs to be rewritten.

Comment: @CrisLuengo That's what I'm trying to understand.  I would much rather prefer to run func.start in the function itself.  I guess the question is, when you compile, is there only 'one' workspace assuming you include the func.start.m function along with the compilation?  In that case, it would make sense to just call the function directly.  I hope this is making sense.

Comment: Every function has its own workspace. The base workspace exists in an interactive session, not sure if it exists for a compiled MATLAB program too. But `eval` and related are blocked by the compiler (as far as I know) because it could circumvent license requirements for MATLAB use.

Comment: what does `func.start` do thats the really important point - if you provide some info on that you might get some meaningful suggestions/help.  What happens in `matlab` when you run the `func.start` in the function itself?